# Alternating product of binomial powers on descending natural numbers

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

While trying to prove something completely different I noticed a strange combinatorial result looks like it would follow:

For $n, t\in \mathbb{N}$ with $n\geq 2$ and $t \geq 1$
$$
\frac{(n)^{^{n-t}C_{n-t}} (n-2)^{^{n-t}C_{n-t-2}} \cdots }{(n-1)^{^{n-t}C_{n-t-1}} (n-3)^{^{n-t}C_{n-t-3}}\cdots} \to 1 \quad \text{as} \quad n\to \infty.
$$

The case with $t=2$ popped out of what I was doing, but it appears to be true for any $t \geq 1$.

For example, we have for $n=5$ and $t=2$ that
$$
\frac{5^1 \cdot 3^3}{4^3 \cdot 2^1} \approx 1.0547
$$

N.B. I'm taking $^nC_r$ for $r < 0$ to be $0$.

Does this result have a name or an obvious proof? I haven't seen binomial coefficients appear in powers before.

Comment: When $n=2$ your quotient equals $0$.

Comment: Could you briefly outline how you showed (or found) the $t=2$ case? Perhaps it’s generalisable?